# MVVM & Entity Framework - What raises events?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, mvvm, poco

I have recently been looking into a database solution and came across Entity Framework. I am using Code First to generate tables but while attempting to correctly structure the layout of my code I came across a problem with the design.

The general MVVM design I tend to follow is that both the Model and the ViewModel inherit INotifyProperty so the ViewModel's can listen to when any changes happen in the model they are bound to.

However, in the case of an SQL Database and EntityFramework. My models all essentially inherit DbContext and are POCO objects.

So if the Model no longer has a way of raising events and so the view models can no longer listen to the changes. What happens when ViewModelA makes a change to an item in the model (sql database). How does ViewModelB know it has changed so it can update accordingly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your "Plain old CLR objects" (POCOs) should not inherit from `DbContext`. Rather, with Entity Framework (Code First), your application will typically have a single class that inherits from `DbContext`. This class will generally contain several `DbSet` properties, which are collections of your POCOs.

Second of all, even if your POCOs did inherit from some base class, there's no reason they couldn't *also* implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. C# doesn't support multiple inheritance, but it does allow a class to *implement* an interface even if it also inherits from a base class. In fact, a class can inherit from *multiple* interfaces as well as inherit from a base class.

With these two points in mind, there's no reason your POCOs could not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Whether that's really the best architecture is another question, and the answer is honestly a big "it depends".

I personally don't use `INotifyPropertyChanged` on POCOs. Instead, I usually have commands in my view model that respond to user actions (such as clicking a Submit button). These commands often just change something directly on the same view model, but if they result in a change to the model, they will either directly change some data on an entity or delegate to a class that handles such things (depending on the complexity of the application). If the commands do cause a change to the database *and* other view models need to know about this, I use a messenger (which is a basic feature of most MVVM frameworks) to publish a message indicating that something has changed (plus other useful data if necessary), and let the other view models register for the message and respond accordingly.

Comment: Are you implying that my POCO's can contain ObservableCollections and inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged and it will function as expected?

Comment: Yes, POCOs can contain ObservableCollections properties and implement (not inherit) INotifyPropertyChanged. Note that, to take advantage of EntityFramework's lazy loading and other features, you will want to mark your collections that are also navigation properties as `virtual`.

Comment: What do you mean implement and not inherit? How does that work?

Comment: It's just terminology. You inherit a class, you implement an interface. The key thing to remember is that you implement multiple interfaces, but you can only inherit one class.